# Why CsvHelper does not read data from CSV files

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I'm trying to create a windows service that detects if there are new CSV files in a folder and parse those files. CsvHelper seems to not be able to read the CSV file. All the parameters that I try to populate are empty.

Is there something wrong in the code? The GetField method does not return any values and If I print the parameters are all empty.

The path is correct and the csv files paths are also correct.

```
public class CSVBatch
{
    public string MaterialID { get; set; }
    public string MaterialName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string BatchID { get; set; }
    public string ProcessOrder { get; set; }
    public string Recipe { get; set; }

    public List<CSVRawMaterial> CSVRawMaterials { get; set; }
    public class CSVRawMaterial
    {
        public string MaterialID { get; set; }
        public string MaterialName { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string BatchID { get; set; }
        public string ProcessOrder { get; set; }
        public string Recipe { get; set; }
    }
}

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        
        var folder = "C:\\BOM";
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(folder);
        var fw = fileSystemWatcher;
        fw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fw.Created += Newfileevent;
    }       
     
    static void Newfileevent(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\BOM");

        foreach (string s in filePaths)
        {
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = ",",
                MissingFieldFound = null,
                TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
                HeaderValidated = null,
                HasHeaderRecord = true
            };
            using (var reader = new StringReader(s))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
            {                   
                csv.Read();
                var batch = new CSVBatch
                {
                    MaterialID = csv.GetField<string>(0),
                    MaterialName = csv.GetField<string>(1),
                    Location = csv.GetField<string>(2),
                    Quantity = csv.GetField<string>(3),
                    BatchID = csv.GetField<string>(4),
                    ProcessOrder = csv.GetField<string>(5),
                    Recipe = csv.GetField<string>(6)
                };

                csv.Read();
                var rawMaterials = new List<CSVRawMaterial>();

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    var rawmaterial = new CSVRawMaterial
                    {
                        MaterialID = csv.GetField<string>(0),
                        MaterialName = csv.GetField<string>(1),
                        Location = csv.GetField<string>(2),
                        Quantity = csv.GetField<string>(3)
                    };

                    rawMaterials.Add(rawmaterial);
                }

                batch.CSVRawMaterials = rawMaterials;
            }
        }
```

**CSV File**:

[image: CSV File]

Comment: If you're detecting when a file is created then you're going to detect an empty file that may even be locked. You need to wait until the file has been written before reading it. There's no specific event for that so you need to be a bit clever. There should be at least one `Changed` event after the `Created` event so you can wait for a certain period of time after the last `Changed` event for the new file and then read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues.

1. You are using `StringReader` instead of `StreamReader`. It should be:

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
```

2. If you have a header row, you also have to specifically read the header when reading by hand.

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{                   
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();

    csv.Read();
    batch = new CSVBatch
    {
```